# How to scrape multiple metadata in python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, wget

I want to make a personal Instagram downloader tool. Which is using BeautifulSoup4 and Requests library. I will just put the URL of the photo or the video. Instagram has a different property for image and video. 
For video they have og:video and for image they have og:image property. 
I just want to check if it's image, then collect the image link from metadata. Or, if it's a video, collect the direct video link and download it using wget.

I am trying if property == "og:video": 
                    code
             elif property =="og:video":
                    code
But, it seems it doesn't work at all.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import wget
url = input("Enter Instagram Video/Pic URL: ")
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

for data in soup.find_all('meta'):
    if soup.find_all('meta', property="og:video"):
        x = data["content"]
    elif soup.find_all('meta', property="og:image"):
        x = data["content"]
wget.download(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `for` loop, you are calling the `find_all` method again in the `soup` object, where you should be checking in each `data` object. Try this:

```
for data in soup.find_all('meta'):
    if data.get('property') == "og:video":
        x = data.get("content")
    elif data.get('property') == "og:image":
        x = data.get("content")
```